# Creating Array of matrices without for loop

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

Using the following loop, I can create an array of 4 matrices. Is there any function to create this array without for loop. Using outer function, I can create the matrices individually.

```
time=c(0,0.5,0.7) 
beta=matrix(1:40, nrow=5, ncol=8)
array_mat <- array(NA, dim = c(5, 3, 4))
for (i in 1:5) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    for (k in 1:4) {
      array_mat[i, j, k] <- beta[i, k * 2 - 1] + beta[i, k * 2] * time[j]
    }
  }
}
```

The output is

```
array_mat
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1  4.0  5.2
[2,]    2  5.5  6.9
[3,]    3  7.0  8.6
[4,]    4  8.5 10.3
[5,]    5 10.0 12.0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   11 19.0 22.2
[2,]   12 20.5 23.9
[3,]   13 22.0 25.6
[4,]   14 23.5 27.3
[5,]   15 25.0 29.0

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   21 34.0 39.2
[2,]   22 35.5 40.9
[3,]   23 37.0 42.6
[4,]   24 38.5 44.3
[5,]   25 40.0 46.0

, , 4

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   31 49.0 56.2
[2,]   32 50.5 57.9
[3,]   33 52.0 59.6
[4,]   34 53.5 61.3
[5,]   35 55.0 63.0
```

Can I do it without using for loop or using any other function? Appreciate your help.

Comment: @akrun I can create any of the four matrices using outer() function. I am looking a function like outer() or any other function to create this array of matrices.

Comment: IN that case `out <- crossing(v1 = 1:5, v2 = 1:3, v3 = 1:4) %>% pmap_dbl(~ beta[..1, ..3 * 2 - 1] + beta[..1, ..3 * 2] * time[..2])`

Comment: Would just one loop be of interest to you?

Comment: I would love to see the loop.  @RuiBarradas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242447/creating-array-of-matrices-without-for-loop/57243254#57243254) but given the OP's [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242447/creating-array-of-matrices-without-for-loop#comment100987103_57242447) to my comment, here it goes.

```
array_mat2 <- array(NA, dim = c(5, 3, 4))
for(j in 1:3){
  array_mat2[, j, ] <- beta[, 2*(1:4) - 1] + beta[, 2*(1:4)]*time[j]
}
identical(array_mat, array_mat2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Can you please see this problem 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57679795/storage-problem-in-r-alternative-to-nested-loop-for-creating-array-of-matrices

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure array-based approach:

```r
time <- c(0, 0.5, 0.7) 
beta <- matrix(1:40, nrow = 5, ncol = 8)

aperm(
    outer(beta[, 2*1:4], time) +    # multiply even cols by time
        replicate(3, beta[, 2*1:4 - 1]),    # add odd cols
    c(1, 3, 2)    # rearrange
)
#> , , 1
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1  4.0  5.2
#> [2,]    2  5.5  6.9
#> [3,]    3  7.0  8.6
#> [4,]    4  8.5 10.3
#> [5,]    5 10.0 12.0
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]   11 19.0 22.2
#> [2,]   12 20.5 23.9
#> [3,]   13 22.0 25.6
#> [4,]   14 23.5 27.3
#> [5,]   15 25.0 29.0
#> 
#> , , 3
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]   21 34.0 39.2
#> [2,]   22 35.5 40.9
#> [3,]   23 37.0 42.6
#> [4,]   24 38.5 44.3
#> [5,]   25 40.0 46.0
#> 
#> , , 4
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]   31 49.0 56.2
#> [2,]   32 50.5 57.9
#> [3,]   33 52.0 59.6
#> [4,]   34 53.5 61.3
#> [5,]   35 55.0 63.0
```

Comment: Can you please explain c(1, 3, 2) rearrange term? @alistaire

Comment: `aperm` is like `t` generalized for arrays. There's not just one transposition, though, so you need to specify the order in which to rearrange the dimensions, where 1 is rows, 2 is columns, 3 is the third dimension, etc., so `aperm(mat, c(2, 1))` is the same as `t(mat)`. Here `aperm(..., c(1, 3, 2))` means it's flipping the second and third dimensions and keeping rows in place.

Comment: if I want to add another term like `beta[, 2*1:4], time^2`  in the model, how can I add the term?

Comment: Can you please see this problem
(]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57679795/storage-problem-in-r-alternative-to-nested-loop-for-creating-array-of-matrices )