# storage problem in R. alternative to nested loop for creating array of matrices and then multiple plots

Tags: matrix, nested, store

With the following pieces of information, I can easily create an array of matrices

```
b0=data.frame(b0_1=c(11.41,11.36),b0_2=c(8.767,6.950))
b1=data.frame(b1_1=c(0.8539,0.9565),b1_2=c(-0.03179,0.06752))
b2=data.frame(b2_1=c(-0.013020 ,-0.016540),b2_2=c(-0.0002822,-0.0026720))
T.val=data.frame(T1=c(1,1),T2=c(1,2),T3=c(2,1))
dt_data=cbind(b0,b1,b2,T.val)
fu.time=seq(0,50,by=0.8)
pat=ncol(T.val) #number of T's
nit=2 #no of rows

pt.array1=array(NA, dim=c(nit,length(fu.time),pat)) 

for ( it.er in 1:nit){
  for ( ti in 1:length(fu.time)){
    for (pt in 1:pat){
      pt.array1[it.er,ti,pt]=b0[it.er,T.val[it.er,pt]]+b1[it.er,T.val[it.er,pt]]*fu.time[ti]+b2[it.er,T.val[it.er,pt]]*fu.time[ti]^2
    }
  }
}

pt.array_mean=apply(pt.array1, c(3,2), mean)
pt.array_LCL=apply(pt.array1, c(3,2), quantile, prob=0.25)
pt.array_UCL=apply(pt.array1, c(3,2), quantile, prob=0.975)
```

Now with these additional data, I can create three plots as follows

```
    mydata
       pt.ID      time IPSS
1      1  0.000000   10
2      1  1.117808    8
3      1  4.504110    5
4      1  6.410959   14
5      1 13.808220   10
6      1 19.890410    4
7      1 28.865750   15
8      1 35.112330    7
9      2  0.000000    6
10     2  1.117808    7
11     2  4.109589    8
12     2 10.093151    7
13     2 16.273973   11
14     2 18.345205   18
15     2 21.567120   14
16     2 25.808220   12
17     2 56.087670    5
18     3  0.000000    8
19     3  1.413699    3
20     3  4.405479    3
21     3 10.389041    8


pdf("plots.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(3,2))
for( pt.no in 1:pat){
  plot(IPSS[ID==pt.no]~time[ID==pt.no],xlim=c(0,57),ylim=c(0,35),type="l",col="black",
      xlab="f/u time", ylab= "",main = paste("patient", pt.no),data=mydata)
  points(IPSS[ID==pt.no]~time[ID==pt.no],data=mydata)
  lines(pt.array_mean[pt.no,]~fu.time, col="blue")
  lines(pt.array_LCL[pt.no,]~fu.time, col="green")
  lines(pt.array_UCL[pt.no,]~fu.time, col="green")
}
dev.off()
```

The problem arise when the number of rows in each matrix is much bigger say 10000. It takes too much computation time to create the `pt.array1` for large number of rows in `b0`, `b1` and `b2`.
Is there any alternative way I can do it quickly using any builtin function?
Can I avoid the storage allocation for `pt.array1` as I am not using it further? I just need `pt.array_mean`, `pt.array_UCL` and `pt.array_LCL` for `myplot`.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Rui Barradas can you please check it

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here ? There is propably much faster than nested loop if you can guide me a little

Comment: The for loop is taking too much time? Can I use any other function to create the `pt.array1` matrix? I have made another similar post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57618368/nested-loop-in-r-for-creating-arrays-of-matrices . You can have a look

Comment: I'd be glad to help you with your request on that post but I've no experience with arrays, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of other approaches you can employ.

First, you largely have a model of `b0 + b1*fu + b2*fu^2`. Therefore, you could make the coefficients and apply the `fu` after the fact:

```
ind <- expand.grid(nits = seq_len(nit), pats = seq_len(pat))
mat_ind <- cbind(ind[, 'nits'], T.val[as.matrix(ind)])

b_mat <- matrix(c(b0[mat_ind], b1[mat_ind], b2[mat_ind]), ncol = 3)

b_mat
       [,1]     [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 11.410  0.85390 -0.0130200
[2,] 11.360  0.95650 -0.0165400
[3,] 11.410  0.85390 -0.0130200
[4,]  6.950  0.06752 -0.0026720
[5,]  8.767 -0.03179 -0.0002822
[6,] 11.360  0.95650 -0.0165400
```

Now if we apply the model to each row, we will get all of your raw results. The only problem is that we don't match your original output - each column slice of your array is equivalent of a row slice of my matrix output.

```
pt_array <- apply(b_mat, 1, function(x) x[1] + x[2] * fu.time + x[3] * fu.time^2)

pt_array[1,]
[1] 11.410 11.360 11.410  6.950  8.767 11.360

pt.array1[, 1, ]
      [,1]  [,2]   [,3]
[1,] 11.41 11.41  8.767
[2,] 11.36  6.95 11.360
```

That's OK because we can fix the shape of it as we get summary statistics - we just need to take the `colSums` and `colQuantiles` of each row converted to a 2 x 3 matrix:

```
library(matrixStats)

pt_summary = array(t(apply(pt_array,
                         1,
                         function(row) {
                           M <- matrix(row, ncol = pat)
                           c(colMeans2(M),colQuantiles(M, probs = c(0.25, 0.975))
                           )
                           }
                         )),
                   dim = c(length(fu.time), pat, 3),
                   dimnames = list(NULL, paste0('pat', seq_len(pat)), c('mean', 'LCL', 'UCL'))
)

pt_summary[1, ,] #slice at time = 1

        mean      LCL      UCL
pat1 11.3850 11.37250 11.40875
pat2  9.1800  8.06500 11.29850
pat3 10.0635  9.41525 11.29518

# rm(pt.array1)
```

Then to do your final graphing, I simplified it - the `data` argument can be a `subset(mydata, pt.ID == pt.no)`. Additionally, since the summary statistics are now in an array format, `matlines` allows everything to be done at once:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,2))

for( pt.no in 1:pat){
  plot(IPSS~pt.ID, data=subset(mydata, pt.ID == pt.no),
       xlim=c(0,57), ylim=c(0,35),
       type="l",col="black", xlab="f/u time", ylab= "",
       main = paste("patient", pt.no)
       )

  points(IPSS~time, data=subset(mydata, pt.ID == pt.no))

  matlines(y = pt_summary[,pt.no ,], x = fu.time, col=c("blue", 'green', 'green'))
}
```

[image: R matlines]

Comment: with `sd=c(0.5879,0.8946)`  I would like to add two more funnctions  `b0 + b1*fu + b2*fu^2+2*sqrt(sd)` and   `b0 + b1*fu + b2*fu^2-2*sqrt(sd)` and then only take the `mean` value not `LCL` and `UCL`. How can I add these two functions ? Thanks for your help @Cole

Comment: You probably should make another question. But if this is just a scalar, it looks like you could do ```pt_array_sd1_pos<- pt_array +2*sqrt(sd[1])```. Would be labor intensive but work