# same loop for all column in R to create new data frame

Tags: r, loops, matrix

For the following data frame,

```
mydata=data.frame(x1=c(4,8,7,12,10),x2=c(5,7,18,4,12),x3=c(10,12,5,2,14))
mydata
  x1 x2 x3
1  4  5 10
2  8  7 12
3  7 18  5
4 12  4  2
5 10 12 14
```

I would like to create a new 3 columns where each column will be created by repeating each element 12 times. For the first new column,

```
y1=matrix(NA, nrow=5,ncol=12)
for ( g in 1:5){
  y1[g,]=rep(mydata$x1[g],12)
}
ynew_1=c(apply( y1, 1, c))
```

ynew_1

```
 4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  7  7  
7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

I can create ynew_2 and ynew_3 in a similar way. **Can I use any function or loop to create these new variables**? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I a having trouble understanding. When you say *"I would like to create a new 3 columns"*, do you mean 3 new data frames? Or 3 new vectors? Because your code shows 12 columns, not 3. Is `ynew1` your expected result, or just a failed attempt? Does the result need to be a data frame, or is a vector okay? I think, maybe, you want `ynew1 = rep(mydata$x1, each = 12)`?

Comment: Generally, we advise against sequentially naming variables, e.g., `ynew1`, `ynew2`, `ynew3`. It's almost always better to put them in a list, or a data frame, or a matrix, etc. Something like `ynew = sapply(mydata, rep, each = 12)` will give a nice matrix.

Comment: @Gregor, I would like to create a new data frame of three columns `ynew_1`, `ynew_2` and `ynew_3`. If I have a large data set containing 100 columns and I would like to work with some of the columns to create the new data frame, then how can I work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `tidyr`

```
newdata <- mydata %>% uncount(12)
```

`uncount` "duplicates rows according a variable or expression", It does what you need without slowing down your code with a loop and keep it as a dataframe.

Comment: Can you please see this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57679795/storage-problem-in-r-alternative-to-nested-loop-for-creating-array-of-matrices