# Multiple function for the same data in r

Tags: r, function, loops, matrix

With the following information,

```
b0=data.frame(b0_1=c(11.41,11.36),b0_2=c(8.767,6.950))
b1=data.frame(b1_1=c(0.8539,0.9565),b1_2=c(-0.03179,0.06752))
b2=data.frame(b2_1=c(-0.013020 ,-0.016540),b2_2=c(-0.0002822,-0.0026720))
z=data.frame(z1=c(0.25,0.47),z2=c(0.48,0.57),z3=c(0.25,0.64))
T.val=data.frame(T1=c(1,1),T2=c(1,2),T3=c(2,1))
dt_data=cbind(b0,b1,b2,T.val,z)
fu.time=seq(0,2,by=0.8)
pat=ncol(T.val) #number of T's
nit=2 #no of rows
sd.val=c(0.48,0.65)
```

I can calculate three different functions. The first function is `b0 + b1*fu + b2*fu^2+z.` and calculated as

```
pt.array1=array(NA, dim=c(nit,length(fu.time),pat)) 

for ( it.er in 1:nit){
  for ( ti in 1:length(fu.time)){
    for (pt in 1:pat){
      pt.array1[it.er,ti,pt]=b0[it.er,T.val[it.er,pt]]+b1[it.er,T.val[it.er,pt]]*fu.time[ti]+b2[it.er,T.val[it.er,pt]]*fu.time[ti]^2+z[it.er,pt]
    }
  }
}
```

Now finding the mean and quantiles as

```
pt.array1.mean=apply(pt.array1,c(3,2), mean)
pt.array1.LCI=apply(pt.array1,c(3,2), quantile, prob=0.25)
pt.array1.UCI=apply(pt.array1,c(3,2), quantile, prob=0.975)
```

The second function is `b0 + b1*fu + b2*fu^2+z+2*sqrt(sd.val)` and calculated as 
`

```
pt.array_UPI=array(NA, dim=c(nit,length(fu.time),pat)) 

for ( it.er in 1:nit){
  for ( ti in 1:length(fu.time)){
    for (pt in 1:pat){
      pt.array_UPI[it.er,ti,pt]=b0[it.er,T.val[it.er,pt]]+b1[it.er,T.val[it.er,pt]]*fu.time[ti]+b2[it.er,T.val[it.er,pt]]*fu.time[ti]^2+z[it.er,pt]+2*sqrt(sd.val[it.er])
    }
  }
}

pt.array_UPI.mean=apply(pt.array_UPI, c(3,2), mean)
```

The third function is 
`b0 + b1*fu + b2*fu^2+z-2*sqrt(sd.val)` and calculated as

```
pt.array_LPI=array(NA, dim=c(nit,length(fu.time),pat)) 

for ( it.er in 1:nit){
  for ( ti in 1:length(fu.time)){
    for (pt in 1:pat){
      pt.array_LPI[it.er,ti,pt]=b0[it.er,T.val[it.er,pt]]+b1[it.er,T.val[it.er,pt]]*fu.time[ti]+b2[it.er,T.val[it.er,pt]]*fu.time[ti]^2+z[it.er,pt]+2*sqrt(sd.val[it.er])
    }
  }
}

pt.array_LPI.mean=apply(pt.array_LPI, c(3,2), mean)
```

`

All of the codes work well. My question is,
Can I calculate all of these functions in one loop or using any other function?.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Read up on the apply functions in R. When you find yourself writing triply nested for loops, it's time to refactor your code.

Comment: Any specific link, please? @BillO'Brien

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/r-apply-sapply-tapply.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue on the previous answer:

[storage problem in R. alternative to nested loop for creating array of matrices and then multiple plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57679795/storage-problem-in-r-alternative-to-nested-loop-for-creating-array-of-matrices)

We can simplify your loops to this:

```
library(matrixStats)

ind <- expand.grid(nits = seq_len(nit), pats = seq_len(pat))
mat_ind <- cbind(ind[, 'nits'], T.val[as.matrix(ind)])

b_mat <- matrix(c(b0[mat_ind], b1[mat_ind], b2[mat_ind], z[mat_ind], sd.val[ind$nits]), ncol = 5)

colnames(b_mat) <- c('b0','b1','b2','z','sd.val')
b_mat 

#         b0       b1         b2    z sd.val
#[1,] 11.410  0.85390 -0.0130200 0.25   0.48
#[2,] 11.360  0.95650 -0.0165400 0.47   0.65
#[3,] 11.410  0.85390 -0.0130200 0.25   0.48
#[4,]  6.950  0.06752 -0.0026720 0.57   0.65
#[5,]  8.767 -0.03179 -0.0002822 0.48   0.48
#[6,] 11.360  0.95650 -0.0165400 0.47   0.65

pt_matrix_no_sd <- apply(b_mat, 1, function(x) x[1] + x[2] * fu.time + x[3] * fu.time^2 + x[4])
pt_matrix_pos_sd <- apply(b_mat, 1, function(x) x[1] + x[2] * fu.time + x[3] * fu.time^2 + x[4] + 2 * x[5])
pt_matrix_neg_sd <- apply(b_mat, 1, function(x) x[1] + x[2] * fu.time + x[3] * fu.time^2 + x[4] - 2 * x[5])
```

If you notice, the last 3 lines share a lot of elements in common. When we are only adding a constant, we can use `sweep`. For each column in `pt_matrix_no_sd`, we are going to add `2 * sd.val` with the following statement:

```
sweep(pt_matrix_no_sd, 2, 2*b_mat[,'sd.val'], FUN = '+')

identical(pt_matrix_pos_sd,
          sweep(pt_matrix_no_sd, 2, 2*b_mat[,'sd.val'], FUN = '+')
) #TRUE
```

Then to get your summary statistics, we can use `colMeans` or other `colXs` from `matrixStats`:

```
library(matrixStats)
pt_summary = array(t(apply(pt_matrix_no_sd, #change as needed
                         1,
                         function(row) {
                           M <- matrix(row, ncol = pat)
                           c(colMeans2(M),colQuantiles(M, probs = c(0.25, 0.975))
                           )
                           }
                         )),
                   dim = c(length(fu.time), pat, 3),
                   dimnames = list(NULL, paste0('pat', seq_len(pat)), c('mean', 'LCL', 'UCL'))
)

pt_summary[1, ,]   

#        mean      LCL      UCL
#pat1 11.7450 11.70250 11.82575
#pat2  9.5900  8.55500 11.55650
#pat3 10.5385  9.89275 11.76543

pt_summary2 = array(t(apply(pt_matrix_pos_sd, 1, #change as needed
                           function(row) colMeans2(matrix(row, ncol = pat)))),
                    dim = c(length(fu.time), pat, 1),
                    dimnames = list(NULL, paste0('pat', seq_len(pat)), c('mean')))
pt_summary2[1,,]

#   pat1    pat2    pat3 
#12.8750 10.7200 11.6685 

#you should be able to do the negative sd
```